# Opensearch service not reachable to App services on EKS Cluster behind NGINX Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, elastic-stack, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress, opensearch

I am trying to setup my application and opensearch application behind NGINX ingress on EKS as shown below.

[image]

On NGINX Ingress, I setup the routing as below which is working fine:

```
    ---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-opensearch
  namespace: os-dev
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2

spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - acdfdd7b4bsdfe3ed1ae568bc892743e5-022f05b723bf7c62.elb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
    secretName: tls-for-dashboards-key-pair
  rules:
  - host: acdfdd7b4bsdfe3ed1ae568bc892743e5-022f05b723bf7c62.elb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /os(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
             name: opensearch-cluster-master
             port:
               number: 9200
```

The above one is working from browser with https://acdfdd7b4bsdfe3ed1ae568bc892743e5-022f05b723bf7c62.elb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/os.

The service status shows everything looks good:

```
NAMESPACE      NAME                                     TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP                                                                     PORT(S)                      AGE
cert-manager   cert-manager                             ClusterIP      10.100.230.233   <none>                                                                          9402/TCP                     6d8h
cert-manager   cert-manager-webhook                     ClusterIP      10.100.240.163   <none>                                                                          443/TCP                      6d8h
default        kubernetes                               ClusterIP      10.100.0.1       <none>                                                                          443/TCP                      6d11h
ingress        ing-ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.100.69.69     acdfdd7b4bsdfe3ed1ae568bc892743e5-022f05b723bf7c62.elb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com   80:30947/TCP,443:32576/TCP   6d
ingress        ing-ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.100.211.227   <none>                                                                          443/TCP                      6d
kube-system    kube-dns                                 ClusterIP      10.100.0.10      <none>                                                                          53/UDP,53/TCP                6d11h
os-dev         dashboards-opensearch-dashboards         ClusterIP      10.100.85.97     <none>                                                                          5601/TCP                     5d5h
os-dev         opensearch-cluster-master                ClusterIP      10.100.245.3     <none>                                                                          9200/TCP,9300/TCP            5d5h
os-dev         opensearch-cluster-master-headless       ClusterIP      None             <none>                                                                          9200/TCP,9300/TCP            5d5h
```

On the application side, whenever the OpenSearch endpoint is given as opensearch-cluster-master:9200, the application is failing to connect.

However, when I tested from container to ping the OpenSearch container, the ping is working fine but the telnet to port is failing.

Any leads on this really appreciated.

Pod status:

```
[root@ip-172-31-24-175 matilda_deployment]# kubectl get pods -A
NAMESPACE      NAME                                                READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
cert-manager   cert-manager-847544bbd-xbbnj                        1/1     Running            0          6d8h
cert-manager   cert-manager-cainjector-5c747645bf-s4x7k            1/1     Running            0          6d8h
cert-manager   cert-manager-webhook-f588b48b8-rlhq4                1/1     Running            0          6d8h
ingress        ing-ingress-nginx-controller-64b96466c4-lgz4q       1/1     Running            0          6d
kube-system    aws-node-jgz25                                      1/1     Running            0          6d10h
kube-system    aws-node-vf6bl                                      1/1     Running            0          6d10h
kube-system    coredns-f47955f89-9kl8d                             1/1     Running            0          6d11h
kube-system    coredns-f47955f89-jr5xf                             1/1     Running            0          6d11h
kube-system    kube-proxy-krlrh                                    1/1     Running            0          6d10h
kube-system    kube-proxy-mmlkc                                    1/1     Running            0          6d10h
os-dev         app-6c498bd64c-z9hn7                               0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   31         139m
os-dev         dashboards-opensearch-dashboards-655fc6ff46-6gfm4   1/1     Running            0          5d5h
os-dev         opensearch-cluster-master-0                         1/1     Running            0          5d6h
os-dev         opensearch-cluster-master-1                         1/1     Running            0          5d6h
os-dev         opensearch-cluster-master-2                         1/1     Running            0          5d6h
```

Thank you in advance.

**[UPDATE]:** this issue is more application specific where the certificates are generated with wrong domain. Hence closing the issue.

Comment: `...whenever the OpenSearch endpoint is given as opensearch-cluster-master:9200, the application is failing to connect.` - what's the error and can you also show `kubectl get pods -A`?

Comment: It is giving the following error.      / # wget http://opensearch-cluster-master:9200
Connecting to opensearch-cluster-master:9200 (10.100.245.3:9200)
wget: error getting response

Comment: @gohm'c - Updated question with pod status

Comment: `cmdb-6c498bd64c-z9hn7` - your app is not working, it will not be able to connect to your opensearch.

Comment: yes. the app went down because it is not able to establish DB connection. It is springboot application which is trying to connect to DB during startup and failing to start

Comment: try `wget opensearch-cluster-master.os-dev:9200`